# Translation for "reverse engineering"?

Tags: tradução, português-europeu

One of the most important things in engineering is knowing how to pick up a finished project and backtrack in order to obtain the very base of the project at hand. This is called reverse engineering.

*Reverter engenharia*, *engenharia reversa*, and similar wordings aren't a good illustration of what reverse engineering actually is.

Do we have a linguistic **technical** equivalent to reverse engineering?

---

*(Note that Reverse Engineering isn't the same as Engenharia Reversa. The Gerund of Engenharia doesn't exist as Engenharia isn't a verb like "To Engineer" is in english)*

Answer (score 5):

*Engenharia reversa* parece ser a tradução mais comum:

> Este processo de cópia é conhecido como **engenharia reversa**, a qual é... o procedimento pelo qual se decompõe um produto em suas partes para estudar seus parâmetros, características e configurações, com o fim de aprender a reproduzi[-]los, promover algumas melhorias e desenvolver um produto diferenciado, em boa medida, do produto original.

Esta frase foi retirada do [*corpus* TODOS da Linguateca](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=TODOS), onde há 126 ocorrências de *engenharia reversa* (e apenas 3 de *inversa*). Há quem proponha *retroengenharia*, mas essa palavra não aparece no *corpus* ou em qualquer dicionário que tenha consultado.

O Priberam define a expressão assim (dá também *engenharia inversa* como sinónimo):

> **engenharia reversa**
>   • Actividade que consiste em analisar um objecto para perceber o seu funcionamento ou como foi feito.

Repara que o Priberam define *engenharia reversa* como uma *atividade*, não como uma *ciência*. Por isso, parece-me que não deves hesitar muito em usar aqui *engenharia* para significar não uma ciência, mas a atividade de aplicar essa ciência a um caso em particular.

*Desconstrução* também pode ser usado nalguns contextos, já que *desconstruir* pode significar *desfazer para voltar a construir* ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/desconstruir)).

Comment: O Google search e Google Books dão resultados mais ou menos proporcionais para *reversa* versus *inversa*.

Comment: @Jacinto Como é que estás a pesquisar? No Google Books tenho 13 resultados para `"engenharia inversa"` e 140 para `"engenharia reversa"`. Tive de ir até à última página, porque inicialmente dava-me 1900 para "reversa".

Comment: E isto é válido para o Português de Portugal? O problema que encontro é o facto de em PT não se usar "Engenhariando" ou "Fazer Engenharia" (Engenharia é um nome, não um adjectivo ou acção). Em linguagem corrente não vejo problema, mas para um currículo, acção de formação ou mesmo qualquer outro tipo de documentação oficial a utilização desta expressão seria considerada no mínimo estranha

Comment: @Oak Se quiseres podes omitir o verbo (se for uma lista num currículo, por exemplo), ou usar usar outro verbo como _praticar_, ou dizer _participação num projeto de engenharia reversa_

Comment: @Artefacto Eu vi só os números indicados na primeira página. Isso é tramado. Por vezes ir até ao fim altera as proporções.

Comment: @Artefacto Eu estou a preparar uma formação, e um dos objectivos finais é que um formando seja capaz de pegar num circuito e obter as formas mais básicas do sistema. A questão é, o termo técnico é "reverse engineer", mas em português a única forma que consegui sumarizar foi com " Obter forma canónica a partir de um circuito completo" Mas isto não é necessáriamente a definição de reverse engineering

Comment: @Oak Porque não simplesmente _"engenharia reversa de circuito completo"_? Para que precisas do verbo?

Comment: @Oak Editei a resposta para endereçar as tuas preocupações.

Comment: to reverse engineer é o verbo. Como o português usa: engenharia reversa, e reversar também é um verbo em português, pode-se dizer, se fosse necessário, reversar a engenharia de algo. Em todo caso, não vejo nenhum impedimento linguístico ou gramátical. Só porque não se ve no google, não quer dizer que não se pode usar....se concorda com o genio da língua....acho que google é o impedimento nesses casos.

Comment: @Lambie [*Reversar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/reversar) does indeed exist! But it looks as though it means *vomitar*, not what we need in here.

Comment: Então engenharia reversa também fica errado.  Priberam diz o siguiente: ar·re·ve·sar - Conjugar
verbo transitivo
1. Pôr ao revés.
2. Dar sentido contrário a.

"arrevesar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/arrevesar [consultado em 26-04-2016].

Comment: @Lambie _reversa_ é uma palavra diferente, com outros significados: http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/reversa

Comment: arrevesar deveria ser usado: não reversa. Engenharia reversa seria um erro. Tem que ser: engenharia arrevesada [pôr ao revés]

Comment: @Artefacto Se calhar houve um mal-entendido. O que eu quis dizer for: O Google search e Google Books dão resultados mais ou menos proporcionais [aos teus] para reversa versus inversa: 349 mil contra 14 mil.

Comment: @Jacinto ah certo. Pois não tinha percebido a que é que era proporcional, assumi que não sabias o que a palavra queria dizer :p ... ou melhor, que não era um uso literal